# Javascript (jQuery) loaded JSON doesn't update unless I refresh the JSON file in my browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I'm loading the JSON file movies.json so I can get its data. The data is submitted via a POST request which I can confirm automatically updates it just fine. Anyways, when I set the values as a Javascript Array, it doesn't automatically update on the page. The console output shows the previous JSON, for example. To resolve this, I am required to manually go to the json file in my browser, and refresh the page. And then when I refresh the page where I wish to show my json values, it works. Can anyone help me figure this out? I'm fairly new to Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function) {
    $.getJSON("{{ url_for('static', filename='movies.json') }}", function(json){
        var data = [];
        $.each(json, function (index, value) {
            data.push(value); // Puts the JSON values into an array
        });

        console.log(data) // Logs the Array
        var output = document.getElementById('movie'); // Sets output to the movie div
        output.innerHTML = data[0]; // Sets the value to the title of the movie
    });
});
```

This outputs, for example, "Avengers: Infinity war", which can also be seen in my JSON file. But if I send another post request for say, "Batman and Robin", it still outputs "Avengers: Infinity war", while my actual JSON file accurately says "Batman and Robin"

Comment: Take a look at the response headers of the JSON in Network tab of DevTools. How are caching headers delivered, or are they present at all? You should find at least `cache-control: 
no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate` header.

Comment: Well you should create a function to read the json data and whenever you are making post request to save data in json , just call that fucntion on sucess of save post , that should solve your issue

Comment: Since I have absolutely no idea what a response header is, I'd say they are not present. I did check the network tab, and there was nothing there. But I do know that accessing the JSON values through Flask (with open, etc) and Jinja2 updates normally.

Comment: Headers are small pieces of information your server sends to browser as a part of the response to a HTTPRequest. Open the tab, make the AJAX call run on you page, it should appear in the list on the Network tab (Activate XHR-filter if needed) Then click the AJAX row, and see the headers on the right side of the tab.

Comment: "Since I have absolutely no idea what a response header is, I'd say they are not present. "...that's an interesting kind of logic. How can you assert that something is not there when you don't know how to identify it? If someone asked you if there was anything wooden in the room, and you didn't know what wood was, would you say "no, there's none here", or would you say "I need to find about about wood first before I answer"

Comment: ADyson did you read my entire comment? I checked the network tab and was unable to identify it. And then I commented.

Comment: But per your own statement, you still didn't know what you were actually looking for...so how can you claim it's definitely not there? How could you be sure you weren't just looking in slightly the wrong place? (As it turns out, you were probably looking at the wrong _moment in time_, but still. If you had seen an ajax call there, would you have known what to look for? Most browser probably label it "headers" to make it easy, fine, but it's still a rather flawed way of thinking about it IMHO. No hard feelings, just thought it was an interesting approach to take.)

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the problem. I found that my JSON file was being cached, and that clearing my cache fixed the problem. So I looked around and [found this very informative article.](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-json-ajax-caching/)

So I had to add a unique ID to my json file every time it is searched for. My updated code looks like this:

```
$.getJSON("{{ url_for('static', filename='movies.json') }}?id={{ movie_id }}", function(json) {
```

Comment: When setting the response headers correctly on the server, you don't need unique query string for the filename. Make your life easy, and study the headers, if you're planning a full-stack developer carrier, you have to learn the use of the headers anyway.